# JavaScript Filters returning null

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm working on a table in javascript,  with  multiple search criteria  filters = [a,b,c], being grabbed from text fields in my html. The following code returns filtered results as expected:

```
data = [{a: Foo, b: Bar, c:Blah}, {a: Blah, b: Blah, c:Blah}, ...]
     

var filteredData = Data;

var aVal = d3.select('#a').node().value;

filteredData = filteredData.filter(Report => Report.a === aVal);
```

but when I try to loop through all criteria using:

```
  var aVal = d3.select('#a').node().value;
  var bVal = d3.select('#b').node().value;
  var cVal = d3.select('#c').node().value;
  var filters = {"a": aVal, "b": bVal, "c": cVal};

  Object.entries(filters).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    // console.log(MULTIPLE LOGS >> SEE BELOW)
    if (value != "") {      
      filteredData = filteredData.filter(Report => Report.key === value);
    }
  });
```

I get the following results in my console:

> console.log(filteredData)  returns: [{a: Foo, b: Bar, c:Blah}, {a: Foo, b: Bar, c:Blah}, ...]:
>
> console.log(filteredData[0]) returns {a: Foo, b: Bar, c:Blah}
>
> console.log(filteredData[0].a) returns "Foo"
>
> console.log(key, value); returns "a" , "Foo"
>
> console.log(filteredData[0].value) returns NULL
>
> console.log(filters) returns {"Foo", "", ""}
>
> (THESE WERE EXPECTED)
>
> console.log(filteredData[0].key) returns NULL

I know I can use OR statements to filter the table and get the results I want, but as I understand it, if all I entered was aVal, the two filters should be exactly the same. Thanks for your time!

Comment: you have a typo in `if (value != "" {`

Comment: None of your objects have a `key` property. If you want  `key` to be interpreted as a variable use:  `console.log(filteredData[0][key])`

Comment: @MarkMeyer That was the problem thank you!

Comment: this is because you don't have a `key` in your your data, so the array filteredData will be empty after the first iteration. `Report.key === value` should be probably `Report[key] === value`